# connecting to sql database from ASP.NET master page using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

i Have this piece of code connecting to the database

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["savingsConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
string c = "select VersionName ,updated from dbo.DBVersionControl where id = (select max(id) from DBVersionControl)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(c, conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(read.Read())
        {
            Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(read["VersionName"]);
            Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(read["Updated"]);
        }
        conn.Close();
        read.Close();
```

it works when its is located in a normal page but it doesnt work when placed on a master page, no errors are reported though. Is there a way to make this work??

Comment: Where is connection string declaration in given code?

Comment: It is better to connect to a database in your Web.config, that will keep your code clean and will work for every page.

Comment: Did you try to debug this code? What happens when the code reaches the while?

Comment: @SibusisoShongwe Why would you use this connection string in your code like this?

Comment: @Steve, i have used the code in a normal page and it works, but the problem is that it doesn't work when placed in a master page

Comment: @M. Anderson, how should i use it?

Comment: See answer below.

Comment: How do you mean master page? I Hope you use it in a controller?

Comment: [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)  on more about master pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this in your Web.config, with the correct configuration you can use your database in all your Controller's and classes. It is a much cleaner way and edible after you upload your ASP.NET application to a web-server. You can edit the Web.config every time you want. You can't change your connection this easy when you hard-code it in your programm.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="NorthindConnectionString" 
   connectionString=" Server=MyDataServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=Northwind;"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

[See this webpage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178371(v=vs.100).aspx)

[See this video how you make the connection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Giccb5HAdx8)

Comment: Than you have a double connection, you dont need this if you perfer the other method.

Comment: Handy [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mo0ECWKVVDU) for your method. I have used this method too, but I switched to the method I used above.

Comment: Ok i get it now i'll check it out later, but can we get back to the initial problem then .